# gmap3 / google map. Is there a way to detect if a marker is within a cluster or clustered?

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer, jquery-gmap3

I am using the gmap3 ajquery plugin (for google maps v3) to cluster markers on a google map and need to get a list of which markers are within a cluster.

I am struggling to think what else I can tell you about my issue.

The only potential solution I can think of is to loop through all markers and compare their lat / long positions, but that seems so in efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed to [jquery UI map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_api)

It has a function which fetches only markers and not clusters.

```
$('#map').gmap('findMarker', '', '', false, function(marker, found) {
            //do stuff with marker here
        });
```

By removing and re-adding the markers and then redrawing the clusters I have the solution I was after.